# How to detect two enter characters in a row?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a Reddit Formatter tool for whenever you have a text with just one line break to add another and make a new paragraph. Here in StackOverflow it's the same, you have to press the enter key twice to start a new paragraph. It'd go from:

```
 Roses are red
 Violets are Blue
```

to

```
 Roses are red

 Violets are Blue
```

The code below works: it detects enter characters by checking every character from the text you've input in the textbox, starting from the end, and replaces them with a double one after clicking a button

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = textBox1.Text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
             if (textBox1.Text[i] == '\u000A')
             {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(i, "\r\n\r\n");
             }
         }
    }
```

It's great, but I don't want to add more than one enter character if it's already a double. I don't want to go from

```
 Roses are red

 Violets are Blue
```

to

```
 Roses are red


 Violets are Blue
```

because it's already working as the first example. It just adds more lines infinitely if you keep pressing the button.

I've tried with this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = textBox1.Text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {

             if (textBox1.Text[i] == '\u000A' && textBox1.Text[i - 1] != '\u000A')//if finds a SINGLE new line
             {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(i, "\r\n\r\n");
             }
         }
   }
```

But it doesn't work? It's basically the same but also checks if the previous one is an enter character too

What am I doing wrong? I'm really confused because it should work... The output is exactly the same as the first code

Thank you in advance

Comment: First of all change `int i = textBox1.Text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--` to `int i = textBox1.Text.Length - 1; i > 0; i--` else it'll throw exception.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Let's break the question down into 2 parts

**Part #1**: `What am I doing wrong`

Your code checks for 2 consecutive `\n` characters

```
if (textBox1.Text[i] == '\u000A' && textBox1.Text[i - 1] != '\u000A')
```

But you always end up finding the `\r` character at `[i-1]` when you find `\n` at `[i]`. In short your check only works to detect a single `\n` but never more than 1 consecutive EOLNs

**Part #2**: `Best way to do this`

[RegularExpressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) are the best way to handle such things. It not only makes the parsing part easy to read/write (if you know regex), but also retains flexibility when the pattern changes (again if you know regex)

The below line should do what you need

```
textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, "(?:\r\n)+", "\r\n\r\n");
```

Let me explain the regex to you

```
(?:xxx)        This is just a regular bracket (ignore the xxx, as that is just a placeholder) to group together things without capturing them
+              The plus sign after the bracket tells the engine to capture one or more instances of the item preceding it which in this case is `(?:\r\n)`
```

So as you would have realized, we are looking for one or more instances of `\r\n` and replacing it with just one instance of `\r\n`